# kinect data acquiring fps>30

Tags: c#, kinect, frame-rate

I was trying to [Get and Display Depth Data in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131029.aspx) and calculate fps for depth acquisition for kinect.

> To calculate fps for depth implemented a datetime

```
  if (this.sensor != null)
  {
      this.sensor.DepthFrameReady += this.DepthImageReady;
  }

  private void DepthImageReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
  {
     DateTime before = DateTime.Now;
      using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
      {
          if (depthFrame != null)
          {
              depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);
          }
          else
          {
              // depthFrame is null because the request did not arrive in time
          }
      }
     DateTime after = DateTime.Now;
     TimeSpan result = after.Subtract(before);
        float seconds = (float)result.TotalSeconds;
        this.Text = "Kinect (" + (1 / seconds) + "fps)";

  }
```

**I am getting >60 fps and unbelievably infinity sometime**

While kinect gives 30 fps why am i getting infinity, what's wrong am I doing?

Comment: As AlexDev has given you a solution, I have removed this answer to your question _"Looking at your code both the before & after DateTime variables are set to DateTime.Now - so the difference in seconds will be 0. Infinity is the result of a divide by zero."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to measure the interval between each time your function is called, not how long it takes for your function to execute. Something like this:

```
static DateTime lastFrame = DateTime.Now;
private void DepthImageReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthFrame != null)
        {
            depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);
        }
        else
        {
            // depthFrame is null because the request did not arrive in time
        }
    }
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan result = now.Subtract(lastFrame);
    lastFrame = now;
    var milliseconds = result.TotalMilliseconds;

    this.Text = "Kinect (" + (1000.0 / milliseconds) + "fps)";
}
```

Comment: @PaulF TotalSeconds is a double. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx. I had edited the answer according to your comment and I think I will leave it since it's probably more precise.

Comment: Yes - my mistake you are right - I was looking at the Seconds property which is an int.

Comment: @AlexDev would using double or var make a big difference here?

Comment: Not at all. Since TotalMilliseconds returns a double `var milliseconds` will define milliseconds as a double.

Comment: @AlexDev can you help me understand what is a frame? Acquisition (kinect)+ process(change RGB values)+ display = 1 frame or process + projection = 1 frame ?